# Regex, Remove duplicate paths from delimited string

Tags: c#, regex, perl

I'm trying to remove duplicate file paths from a semicolon delimited strings using a regular expression.  Order of the final paths does not matter.

Example Input:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;
```

Desired Output:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;
```

I have the following regex that works but is very slow when the input strings get very long.  Add to this running it over thousands of lines and the time is takes is very bad.

```
\b([^;]+)(?=.*;\1;);
```

Any tips on how to improve the performance of this is much appreciated!

Comment: Does the order of the paths matter?

Comment: No, just that the duplicates are removed.

Comment: Break the string by semicolon and run some version of `unique` on the obtained array.  Is the program in C# or in Perl?

Comment: Perl or C#? @TroyHarter

Comment: Is it an option to select only the [last occurance](https://regex101.com/r/xzb3KO/1) and then use replace?

Answer (score 8):

Or the C# version:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var paths = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;";

        var cleaned = string.Join(";", new HashSet<string>(paths.Split(';')));

        Console.WriteLine(cleaned);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;
```

Split input at `;`, make it a `HashSet<string>(..)` to get rid of dupes, join with `;` again.

---

**Caveat**: If your paths contain `;` as part of the directory name, this breaks - you would have to get more creative for that case - but the same would be valid for any RegEx you use.

Answer (score 7):

The typical way to remove duplicates in Perl is with a hash. See also [perlfaq4: How can I remove duplicate elements from a list or array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3f)

```
my $str = q{C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3};
my %seen;
my $out = join ';', sort grep { !$seen{$_}++ } split /;/, $str;
print $out, "\n";
__END__
# Output:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6
```

I threw the `sort` in there but you can remove it if you don't need that.

Although you haven't yet specified whether the implementation is supposed to be in C# or Perl, the same idea should apply to C# as well. (*Update:* see [Patrick Artner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961594/9300627))

Note the regex is slow because for every match of `\b([^;]+)`, the engine has to scan the entire rest of the string for the lookahead `.*;\1;`, so it's essentially like having nested loops.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is much simpler to do in perl using perl's hash idiom.

Take a look at this example,

```
@items = (1,2,4,1,1,1);

my %uniq;
undef @uniq{ @items };
my @uniques = keys %uniq;

print join " ",@uniques
```

Output:

```
1 2 4
```

> Each key exists only once in a hash, assigning the same key to a hash multiple times stores only the most recent value associated with that key. This behavior has advantages! For example, to find unique elements of a list:
>
> Using **undef** with a hash slice sets the values of the hash to undef. This idiom is the **cheapest way** to perform set operations with a hash.

The above was taken from the book **Modern perl books** Here's the link for you to check up. [Hash idioms](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/03-perl-language.html#VGhlVGVybmFyeUNvbmRpdGlvbmFsT3BlcmF0b3I)

We can clearly make use of this in your scenario.

```
use feature "say";

my $sample_text= C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;;

#Split the paths seperated by ';' into an array of paths 
my @path_arr=  split /;/,$sample_text;

say "Path files with duplicates";
print join "\n",@path_arr;
print "------------------------";

my %temp_hash;                     } THIS 
undef @temp_hash{@path_arr};       }    IS WHAT 
my @unique  = keys %temp_hash;     }       YOU WANT

say "Path files without duplicates";

print join "\n",@unique;
```

Ouput:

```
Path files with duplicates:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3
-----------------------------
Path files without duplicates:
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5
```

I believe this is the fastest way to achieve what you want. If performance is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```js
var inputStr = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path1;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path5;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path1;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path6;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path1;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path3;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path1;C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TESTING\\path3"

var urlArr = inputStr.split(";");
var uniqueUrlList = [];

urlArr.forEach(function (elem, indx1) {
    let foundElem = uniqueUrlList.find((x, indx2)=>{
        return x.toUpperCase() === elem.toUpperCase() &&
        (indx1 != indx2);
    });    
    
    if (foundElem === undefined) {
        uniqueUrlList.push(elem);
    }
});

console.log(uniqueUrlList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl, most optimized one-liner RegEx version:

```
(?<![^;])([^;]++;)(?=(?>[^;]*;)*?\1)
```

On your own input string, your own regex takes ~114000 steps to find all matches but with this one it takes 567 steps to accomplish.

Over 40000 occurrences found in ~4 seconds:

[image]

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/La4Y60/1)

RegEx Breakdown:

```
(?<!    # A Negative lookbehind
    [^;]    # Should be anything other than `;`
)   # End of lookbehind
(   # Capturing group #1
    [^;]++; # Match anything up to first `;`
)   # End of CG #1
(?= # A Positive lookahead
    (?>[^;]*;)*?    # Skip over next path, don't backtrack
    \1  # Until an occurrence
)   # End of lookahead
```

Comment: A very nice optimization  Although `split` is still significantly faster: https://gist.github.com/haukex/eeebfdaf0951e32be4d0cb5eee3e982d

Comment: Why are you claiming ***most optimised***? That's a very hard thing to prove.

Comment: Because I know what I'm talking about?! It eliminates much of backtracks and fails soon encountering a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;

my $paths = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;';

print "$paths\n";
{
    my %temporary_hash = map { $_ => 1 } split( q{;}, $paths );
    $paths = join( q{;}, keys %temporary_hash );
}
print "$paths\n";
```

See [`perldoc -q duplicate`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-remove-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-or-array%3F).

Answer (score 0):

In Perl it takes one line to do it using the library [`List::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.50/lib/List/Util.pm) which is core and highly optimized:

```
my $newpaths = join ';', uniq split /;/, $paths;
```

How does it work? `split` will create a list of paths splitting around the `;` character;`uniq` will make sure there are no repetitions; `join` will create a string of paths separated with `;` again.

If the case of the paths is not important, then:

```
my $newpaths = join ';', uniq split /;/, lc $paths;
```

The full program could be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( uniq );

my $paths = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;';

my $newpaths = join ';', uniq split /;/, $paths;

print $newpaths, "\n";
```

To make things interesting, let's time this solution against the proposed one that uses a temporaty hash. This is the timing program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( uniq );
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

my @p;
for( my $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) {
  push @p, 'C:\This\is\a\random\path' . int(rand(250000));
}
my $paths = join ';', @p;

my $t = time();
my $newpaths = join ';', uniq split /;/, $paths;
$t = time() - $t;
print 'Time with uniq: ', $t, "\n";

$t = time();
my %temp = map { $_ => 1 } split /;/, $paths;
$newpaths = join ';', keys %temp;
$t = time() - $t;
print 'Time with temporaty hash: ', $t, "\n";
```

It generates 1 million random paths which should have a ratio of 5:1 duplicates (5 duplicates of each path). The timings for the server where I have tested this are:

```
Time with uniq: 0.849196910858154
Time with temporaty hash: 1.29486703872681
```

Which makes the `uniq` library faster than the temporary hash. With 100:1 duplicates:

```
Time with uniq: 0.526581048965454
Time with temporaty hash: 0.823433876037598
```

With 10000:1 duplicates:

```
Time with uniq: 0.423808097839355
Time with temporaty hash: 0.736939907073975
```

Both algorithms work less the more duplicates found. `uniq` performs consistently better as the duplicates increase.

Feel free to play with the numbers of the random generator.

Answer (score -2):

Since these are case-insensitive Windows paths, you presumably want to remove elements that are identical except for case

(The next step would be to push each element through `File::Spec::canonpath` to find whether the paths are the same but differently-expressed, and then perhaps to account for links, but this is just about case-insensitivity)

I don't know whether your request *"using a regular expression"* is a requirement, but it is, as you have found, a hugely inefficient way to do this

I recommend a simple `split` on semicolons, and
[`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy)
to do the case-independent uniqueness

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use List::UtilsBy 'uniq_by';

my $p = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;';

my $newp = join "", map { "$_;" } uniq_by { lc } split /;/, $p;

say $newp;
```

#### output

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path1;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path5;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path6;C:\Users\user\Desktop\TESTING\path3;
```